# Wordpress login works partially

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I try to login the user in wordpress, but it works only for users registered in UI, not for the ones added by program.
The Login is done as a response to Ajax login request:

```
//wp_clear_auth_cookie();
$usr = wp_set_current_user ( $user->ID, $user->user_login);
wp_set_auth_cookie  ( $user->ID );
```

There is log output for each step, and for any type of user. It is successfully registered in database, loaded from database, and even login is ok. And even a session is created for both kind of users. It can be seen in the database. But after all login flow, when page is redirected or refreshed, only the UI registered users enters the site. The programmatic ones are just not loaded after all successful steps: silently not working, no errors messages, no warnings, no failures. Looks like it needs some additional steps to enable or to activate. All kind of users are shown in dashboard in UI.

I suspect the programmatically added user is not complete or is not activated. This is how the user is registered as response to Ajax registration request:

```
function register_user($username, $usertype, $externalid)
{
   $user_email =  'theuseremail@mail.com';
   $result = wp_insert_user(array('user_login' => $username,
                                  'nice_name'  => $username,
                                  'user_email' => $user_email,
                                  'user_pass'  => '***********'   ));
   $fb_user_id = $result;
   add_user_meta( $fb_user_id, 'specific_attribute', $specific_id, true );
   $user = get_user_by('id', $fb_user_id);
   return $user;
}
```

The same code is used for both kind of users, the ones registered by UI and the ones registered programatically. There is how the user is loaded from Database as response to Ajax login request:

```
function load_user($usertype, $specific_id)
{
   $user = get_users(array(
        'meta_key'     => 'specific_attribute',
        'meta_value'   => $specific_id
     ));
   return $user [0];
}
```

The login uses a metadata field **specific_attribute** in both cases. For users registered by UI this attribute is added manually in the database, because there is no such UI field. For the other ones it is added automatically in the function **register_user**. The same thing happens when I try to login any user by using standard login/password form.

Workflow update:
1. PHP:

```php
       $user = load_user(request['usertype'], request['specific_id'])
       if not load then register_user(request['username'], request['usertype'], request['specific_id'])
       //wp_clear_auth_cookie();
       $usr = wp_set_current_user ( $user->ID, $user->user_login);
       wp_set_auth_cookie  ( $user->ID );
       do_action( 'wp_login', $user->user_login );
       return $user; //<-- this is returned to javascript Ajax request
    }
```

2. Javascript:

```js
    function onClick()
    {
       let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
          {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
            {
                window.location = redirectaddress; //redirect
                //or window.location=window.location;//just refresh
            }
          }
       xhttp.open("POST", "/wp-json/register_or_login", true);
       xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
       xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(request));
    }
```

Comment: So which part isn't working? the first part?  Do you have any other plugins enabled? `password` should be `user_pass` also in the `wp_insert_user`

Comment: @HowardE There is a clean Wordpress. No plugins installed, except the one developed by me. About which part is not working, is strange, but everything is working. Just everything. I write detailed logs for each step. User is registered, loaded, no problem. It fails after all workflow is successfull and done, I do the redirect and the user is not loaded.

Comment: @HowardE About the user_pass, the workflow of this plugin does not require a password. It is used an external token for authentication instead, see the meta_key.

Comment: Well.. I would leave off `password` from your args then... but as for the login and redirect, can you share that function that you're using?  Can you show the entire workflow, not just the bits and pieces?

Comment: @HowardE
I added **Workflow update:**. This is how all workflow works. I stripped all the extra processing, because all is encoding/decoding json, verify data types, log_error and so on.

Comment: @HowardE if the user is not loaded, it is registered automatically first, then if is registered or loaded it is logged in.

Comment: what are you trying to do here `do_action( 'wp_login', $user->user_login );`

Comment: @HowardE That is just trying different things to make it work. I am not experienced in wordpress, so I am doing experiments to see if it helps.

Comment: you can't `do_action` in your code.  You can `add_action` but the `do_action` is what is fired by the wp core.

Comment: @HowardE I can remove it. In fact it was not here before. But it does not explain why this works for users registered in UI, with do_action, or without it.

Comment: @HowardE I removed the do_action and changed the user_pass. The result is still the same. I have a strange feeling that the user is logged in, but can't see anything, the current user, logout button, profile and so on. There is even a session assigned, it can be seen in the wp_usermeta table. It looks like user is missing some attributes.

Answer (score 1):

In this snippet of code:

```
   $user = load_user(request['usertype'], request['specific_id'])
   if not load then register_user(request['username'], request['usertype'], request['specific_id'])
   //wp_clear_auth_cookie();
   $usr = wp_set_current_user ( $user->ID, $user->user_login);
   wp_set_auth_cookie  ( $user->ID );
   do_action( 'wp_login', $user->user_login );
   return $user; //<-- this is returned to javascript Ajax request
}
```

On the fourth line the $user won't be set to anything if it was just created.

Also on that same line you spelled $user as $usr

I've actually done this exact same thing before. Below is the relevant part of the code that I used when I was doing this.

```
$user_id = lookup_user_id();

// Create the user in the WordPress DB if it does not exist
if ($user_id === false){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    // We're never going to know the password stored in the WordPress DB, but that is alright
    // because we will only authenticate this user against our SSO server and not the WordPress DB
    $password = wp_generate_password(33, true, true);
    $user_id = wp_insert_user( array('user_login'=>$username, 'user_pass'=>$password, 'user_email'=>$email, 'display_name'=>$_POST['username']) );
}

// Login the user
wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id, false);
if (isset($_POST['redirect'])){
    header('Location: '.$_POST['redirect']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I have written script to login and register in WordPress programmatically

Have created an ajax request for login

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_gs_user_login_action', 'gspre_user_login');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_gs_user_login_action', 'gspre_user_login');
function gspre_user_login(){


    $creds = array();
    $username = $creds['user_login'] = $_POST['user_login'];
    $creds['user_password'] = $_POST['user_pass'];

    $userbyname = get_user_by( 'login', $username );
    if ($userbyname) {
        $user = $userbyname;

    }

    $userbyemail = get_user_by('email', $username);
    if ($userbyemail) {
        $user = $userbyemail;
    }

    if ($user) { 

        $user_roles = implode(', ', $user->roles);

        $user = wp_signon( $creds, true );
        if ( is_wp_error($user) ){

            $myArr = array(
            'response' => 'Invalide username and password',
            'redirect_url' => '',
            'message' => $user->get_error_message()
            );

        }else{

            wp_set_current_user( $user->ID );
            wp_set_auth_cookie( $user->ID );

            if ($user_roles == "administrator") {

                $redirect_url = home_url('wp-admin/');

            }else{

                $redirect_url = home_url();
            }

            $myArr = array(
                'response' => 'Login successfully',
                'redirect_url' => $redirect_url,
                'message' => 'Login successfully'
            );
        }


    }else{

        $myArr = array(
        'response' => 'Invalide username and password',
        'redirect_url' => '',
        'message' => $user->get_error_message()
        );

    }


    $myJSON = json_encode($myArr); 
    echo $myJSON;
    die();
}
```

Have created an ajax request for registration

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_gs_user_reg_action', 'gspre_user_reg');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_gs_user_reg_action', 'gspre_user_reg');
function gspre_user_reg(){

    //Create user 

    //start: Fill you details here 
    $user_login = $_POST['user_login']; 
    $user_email = $_POST['email']; 
    $user_pass = $_POST['password']; 
    $display_name = $_POST['display_name']; 
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; 
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; 
    $role = 'administrator';
    //end: Fill you details here 


    $flag_1 = 0;
    $flag_2 = 0;

    $check_username_exists = username_exists( $user_login );
    if ($check_username_exists) {
        $flag_1 = 1;
    }

    $check_email_exists = email_exists($user_email);
    if ($check_email_exists) {
        $flag_2 = 1;
    }


    if ($flag_1 == 0 && $flag_2 == 0) { 

         $userdata = array(
                    'user_login'  =>  $user_login,
                    'user_pass'   =>  $user_pass,
                    'user_email'  =>  $user_email,
                    'display_name'=>  $display_name,
                    'first_name'  =>  $first_name,
                    'last_name'   =>  $last_name
                );

        $user_id = wp_insert_user($userdata);

        wp_update_user( array ('ID' => $user_id, 'role' => $role) );

        if(is_wp_error($user_id)){

            //echo $user->get_error_message();

            $myArr = array(
            'response' => 'register xyz',
            'message' => $user->get_error_message()
            );


        }else{

            //echo "User created successfully";

            $myArr = array(
            'response' => 'register xyz',
            'message' => 'User created successfully'
            );

        }


    }else{

        //echo "User already exist";

        $myArr = array(
        'response' => 'register xyz',
        'message' => 'User already exist'
        );
    }

    $myJSON = json_encode($myArr); 
    echo $myJSON;
    die();
}
```

Also, Have created a shortcode  for login form
Shortcode:: [gsuserlogin]

```
add_shortcode('gsuserlogin', 'gsuserlogin_shortcode_function');
function gsuserlogin_shortcode_function(){

    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        return 'You have Logged in'; 
    }
    ?>
    <form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="" method="post">

        <div class="msg_ajax"></div>

        <div>
            <label for="gs_user_login"><?php echo _e('Username or Email', 'gs-users'); ?></label>
                <input type="text" name="gs_user_login" id="gs_user_login" class="input" value="" size="20">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="gs_user_pass"><?php echo _e('Password', 'gs-users'); ?></label>
                <input type="password" name="gs_user_pass" id="gs_user_pass" class="input" value="" size="20">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label><input name="gs_user_rememberme" type="checkbox" id="gs_user_rememberme" value="true"> <?php echo _e('Remember Me', 'gs-users'); ?></label>
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="gs_user_login_action">

        <input type="button" id="login_btn" value="Login">

    </form> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){

            jQuery(document).on('click', '#login_btn', function(){

                var target = jQuery(this);

                var user_login = jQuery('#gs_user_login').val();

                var user_pass = jQuery('#gs_user_pass').val();

                //Ajax
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php');?>',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {'action': 'gs_user_login_action', user_login: user_login, user_pass: user_pass},
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    beforeSend: function(){
                    },
                    complete: function(){
                    },
                    success: function (response) { console.log(response);

                        jQuery('.msg_ajax').text(response['message']);
                        console.log(response['redirect_url']);
                        console.log(response['message']);

                        if (response['redirect_url']!="") {
                            window.location.href = response['redirect_url'];
                        }


                    }
                });
                //Ajax


            });

        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Created a shortcode for registration form

Shortcode:: [gsuserreg]

```
add_shortcode('gsuserreg', 'gsuserreg_shortcode_function');
function gsuserreg_shortcode_function(){

    if (is_user_logged_in()) {

        return 'You have Logged in'; 

    }

    ?>
    <form name="regform" id="regform" action="" method="post">

        <div class="msg_ajax"></div>

        <div>
            <label for="first_name"><?php echo _e('first_name', 'gs-users'); ?></label>
            <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="last_name"><?php echo _e('last_name', 'gs-users'); ?></label>
            <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="user_login"><?php echo _e('user_login', 'gs-users'); ?></label>
            <input type="text" name="user_login" id="user_login">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="email"><?php echo _e('email', 'gs-users'); ?></label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="password"><?php echo _e('password', 'gs-users'); ?></label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="gs_user_reg_action">

        <input type="button" id="btn_reg" value="Send My Message">

    </form>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){

            jQuery(document).on('click', '#btn_reg', function(){

                var target = jQuery(this);

                var first_name = jQuery('#first_name').val();

                var last_name = jQuery('#last_name').val();

                var user_login = jQuery('#user_login').val();

                var email = jQuery('#email').val();

                var password = jQuery('#password').val();

                //Ajax
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php');?>',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {'action': 'gs_user_reg_action', first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name, user_login: user_login, email: email, password: password},
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    beforeSend: function(){
                    },
                    complete: function(){
                    },
                    success: function (response) { console.log(response);


                        jQuery('.msg_ajax').text(response['message']);
                        console.log(response['response']);
                        console.log(response['message']);


                    }
                });
                //Ajax


            });

        });
    </script>


    <?php

}
```

Paste above code to the theme functions.php
I hope it will work you thank you :)